# Make a SwiftUI button with style .bordered expand to full width

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm trying to make a SwiftUI button with `.buttonStyle(.bordered)` have the full width of the VStack it's in. Here's my button code:

```swift
Button("Save", action:saveUser)
    .frame(maxWidth:.infinity)
    .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
```

In the preview, I can see the actual frame is the full width of its container, but the background provided by the buttonStyle is not:

[image: Button background is not full width]

How can I make the border provided the button style also be full width?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use this way to make a full-width button.

```
Button(action: {
    saveUser()
}) {
    Text("Save").frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
}.buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
```